# Jquery dialog sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/G5RP3/

I have made a div be a dialog through jQuery UI. It is empty at the moment, but what I want to do is make it slide from left to center, from outside the window. What it does instead, is it slides like a drawer is opened. I think I am close, but not sure how to do it.

JS

```
var speed = 2000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginmenu').dialog({
        show: {
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'left',
            speed: speed

        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'slide',
            direction: 'left',
            speed: speed

        },
        modal: true
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="loginmenu"></div>
```

CSS

```
#loginmenu {
}
```

Comment: I think it will not work with dialog's own `show`/`hide` options, you probably will need to make an animation from scratch due to the dialog animation start on dialog's div position

Comment: You want it to _fade in_ from left to center?

Comment: Not really. Just slide with 100% opacity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/MsS9z/1/

```
var speed = 2000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginmenu')
        .on("dialogopen", function() {
            var widget = $(this).dialog("widget");
            var offset = widget.offset();
            widget
                .css("left", -widget.outerWidth() + "px")
                .animate({ left: offset.left }, { duration: speed });
        })
        .dialog({
            modal: true
        });
});
```

When the dialog opens, this code will shift it outside of the screen, then animate the dialog back into place.

---

If you want to slide the dialog to the right on close, things get a bit more complicated:

http://jsfiddle.net/MsS9z/2/

```
var speed = 2000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loginmenu')
        .on("dialogopen", function() {
            var widget = $(this).dialog("widget");
            var offset = widget.offset();
            widget
                .css("left", -widget.outerWidth() + "px")
                .animate({ left: offset.left }, { duration: speed });
        })
        .on("dialogbeforeclose", function() {
            var dialog = $(this);
            var widget = dialog.dialog("widget");

            if (widget.data("dialog-closing") || widget.is(":animated")) {
                widget.data("dialog-closing", false);
                return true;
            }

            widget.data("dialog-closing", true);
            var origOverflow = $("html").css("overflow-x");
            $("html").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
            widget.animate({ left: $(window).width() }, {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function() {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                    $("html").css("overflow-x", origOverflow);
                }
            })

            return false;
        })
        .dialog({
            modal: true
        });
});
```

Here we have to cancel the original dialog close, then trigger the animation, then allow the dialog to close normally. We also have to set the document's `overflow-x` to `hidden` so that the horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear.